# why /var/spool/abrt/ folders not deleted

Tags: linux, redhat, shell-scripting, dump

we try to delete all abrt folders as the following ( on redhat Linux machines )

```
find /var/spool/abrt/*  -type d   -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;
rm '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2018-09-03-14:52:11-5653'
rm '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-03-26-12:18:52-31410'
rm '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-04-07-05:50:25-16907'
rm '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-10-29-14:20:46-20059'


pwd
/var/spool/abrt
```

but we still see the folders and folder content as

```
ls -ltr  /var/spool/abrt
total 24
-rw-------  1 root root   70 Nov  5 09:43 last-ccpp
-rw-------. 1 root root   48 Dec  9 03:25 last-via-server
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec  9 18:45 ccpp-2018-09-03-14:52:11-5653
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec  9 18:45 ccpp-2019-03-26-12:18:52-31410
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec  9 18:45 ccpp-2019-04-07-05:50:25-16907
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec  9 18:45 ccpp-2019-10-29-14:20:46-20059
```

why  `abrt-cli rm` not removed the folders?

from abrt.conf

```
grep -v "^#" /etc/abrt/abrt.conf

MaxCrashReportsSize = 1000
DeleteUploaded = no
AutoreportingEvent = report_uReport
AutoreportingEnabled = no
PrivateReports = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

use the abrt-cli command:

abrt-cli rm directory

here is the help page:

## abrt-cli --help

Usage: abrt-cli [--authenticate] [--version] COMMAND [DIR]...

```
list, ls      List problems [in DIRs]
remove, rm    Remove problem directory DIR
report, e     Analyze and report problem data in DIR
info, i       Print information about DIR
status, st    Print the count of the recent crashes
process, p    Process multiple problems
```

See 'abrt-cli COMMAND --help' for more information